# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '84' for key 'PRIMARY' when update mysql table using mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I am using this code to update mysql 5.7 table in spring boot:

```
    @Override
    public Integer updateOrInsert(SparkGameUserScore score) {
        SparkGameUserScoreExample example = new SparkGameUserScoreExample();
        SparkGameUserScoreExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
        criteria.andGameIdEqualTo(score.getGameId());
        criteria.andUserIdEqualTo(score.getUserId());
        criteria.andTargetUserIdEqualTo(score.getTargetUserId());
        criteria.andVoteRoundEqualTo(score.getVoteRound());
        List<SparkGameUserScore> scores = sparkGameUserScoreMapper.selectByExample(example);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(scores)) {
            return sparkGameUserScoreMapper.insert(score);
        } else {
            return sparkGameUserScoreMapper.updateByExampleSelective(score, example);
        }
    }
```

sometime this code would show error like this:

```
at com.sportswin.soa.spark.biz.GuestMatch.calcSparkScore(GuestMatch.java:97) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.spark.biz.GuestMatch.calcGuestMatchCalc(GuestMatch.java:73) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.spark.controller.impl.SparkGameUserController.calcScore(SparkGameUserController.java:106) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '84' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute$original$Jp9xGgoY(ClientPreparedStatement.java:370) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute$original$Jp9xGgoY$accessor$avRe8pW7(ClientPreparedStatement.java) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
```

why tell the `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '84' for key 'PRIMARY'` error? this code sometimes works fine, sometimes throw the error. I am sure not set the entity id value when execute update operate.

Answer (score 2):

This exception looks like it coming from insertion of data.
It might be an auto increment issue.
Check this answer [java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174756/java-sql-sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-duplicate-entry-0-for-key)

Comment: sometimes works fine, sometimes show this error, I did not change my code, but it works fine now, make me confusing. @Ravi Korrapati

Answer (score 1):

show mapper.xml insert statement, set auto increment id like this?

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Book">
          INSERT INTO tab_products(prod_id,name,description)
      VALUES(SEQ_PRD_ID.nextVal,#{name},#{desc});
</insert>
```